# OpenID endpoints

Tags: openid

I would like to allow users to log in into my website with OpenID. So far I have integrated Google and Yahoo.

What other popular services are offering OpenID login endpoints? I'm particulary interested in Windows Live (but from what I've seen they recently closed the endpoint, and I couldn't find any information about new one). What about social websites, like Facebook or Twitter?

I have seen the [OpenID Directory](http://openiddirectory.com/) but I didn't find any useful information.

Comment: I found a good list of providers and endpoints:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_Providers

I could google a minute more before asking the question. :)
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Facebook doesn't currently support OpenID, as far as I know.  They use OAuth 2.0 instead.  I believe Twitter has switched to OAuth as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look what stackoverflow is offering.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/login

sadly no idea what urls you have to use, but a little choice what is popular so far.

regards

Answer (score 19):

Here are some OpenId endpoints :

- Google : https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
- Google profile : http://www.google.com/profiles/~YOURUSERNAME
- Yahoo : https://me.yahoo.com
- AOL : https://www.aol.com
- Wordpress : http://YOURBLOG.wordpress.com
- LiveJournal : http://www.livejournal.com/openid/server.bml

These following services are **not** OpenId providers and have their own authentication flow :

- Facebook : see a Stackoverflow answer about [how to implement Facebook authentication in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150247/now-how-do-i-authenticate-in-facebooks-php-sdk-3-0-0/6150712#6150712)
- Twitter : see a tutorial about [how to implement Twitter authentication in PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/)

Comment: Google's OpenID endpoint is being deprecated in favor of OpenID Connect: [source](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#shutdown-timetable)

Answer (score 1):

Well if you allow the user to input their own openID url then they can use ANY endpoint. That's the whole point of openID: if you support one endpoint, you support them all. Like StackOverflow, it is best to cover a number of the most popular endpoints so that inputting the openID url is easier (for example, most people don't know the Google OpenID url even if they have an account). You should definitely cover Yahoo, WordPress, Blogger, AOL and MyOpenId like this. But if people like me, who have their own personalised openID url come to your site, they should have the option to use that one.

The OpenID specification actually requires that you provide the URL input box. The input element should also have the OpenID logo as the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it shouldn't matter since the user will supply you with the URL to ask. All OpenID providers work the same way, so the URL should be all you need (see http://openid.net/)

Comment: Or, if you want to make things easier for your users, implement the identifier select feature so they don't have to remember a cryptic URL.

Answer (score 0):

check out [SocialAuth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) or [JOpenId](https://code.google.com/p/jopenid/) for some cool java-based APIs