# How does the DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 2.0 example work?

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I can't seem to manage to get this example to actually run. It just keeps saying no OpenID endpoints found. The sample is found inside the zip download of DotNetOpenAuth.

I am trying to run the OAuth2 project testing the OAuthAuthorizationServer.
So I run the OAuthClient project, click on 
Interop with Authorization Server sample (Authorization code grant) and Resource Server using WCF w/ OAuth 2.0
Then select GetName and hit Request authorization.

It correctly redirects me to the OAuthAuthorizationServer and requests my open id.
Here is where I am stuck. What openid's are it using? What openID can I enter as a test?
I tried using my google openid, didn't work. I have no idea what to do after this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start the **OAuthAuthorizationServer** (this is your AS) project you will see a log on link. This log on link opens the page /Account/LogOn. On the LogOn page you have a input box labeld OpenID. This is expecting the endpoint of your OpenID provider. In the case of Google enter https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id  . See others here [OpenID endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132048/openid-endpoints)

Comment: ok for the openID link. But if I want to make it work with oAuth 2.0 and not openID? How can I do? This sample doesn't issue me a token