# OpenID in PHP Google App Engine

Tags: php, jquery, google-app-engine

I have written an app in PHP and I want to integrate OpenID of any version. I have read lots of the google apps documentation and seen the demo code for Java and Python - which I cannot use.

I have seen a couple of PHP bits generally out there on the web but I don't seem to be able to get them to integrate into my app.

I use Jquery so the JVnace.com thing looked promising but it doesn't actually do anything but loop back to itself with the post variables set up - I don't really know what to do next.

I have read the google documentation on `createLoginUrl()` as it mentions passing the federation ID, but I can't get this to work on my development server - I just get the standard login page - so I'm not going to be able to pull any 'federated' details once I get back into my app.

I have implemented the /_ah/login_required handler but when I use the inbuilt createLoginUrl() it send me to _ah/Login and when it comes back my app doesn't work - I think more of an issue with jquery.

the following site looks easy enough for python (which I can't use)

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Using-OpenID-authentication-on-App-Engine

but it mentions clickpass, which seems to be broken at the moment.

I even looked at this:

http://www.oauthlogin.com/

Which, despite the having to create applications in everything for localhost, appspot and the final domain, looks pretty reasonable, but I have no idea how to hook it into GAE.

Are there any simple enough examples/tutorials of **php** based OpenID authentication for Google App Engine?

Comment: The standart login page is what is displayed for federated login as well for python. It's a dummy login page that mimics the federated behaviour.

Comment: So there is no federation support at all for development side, ok, I'm fine with that, I only need the email address I guesss.so if I deploy the app, it should just magically all work without me providing any OpenId supplier at all?

Comment: Ok, I tried it and I only get a google loging popup, I have set the authentication to the federated option on the application console as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come from Python on GAE but ill try to help

The standard login page is what is displayed for federated login as well for python. It's a dummy login page that mimics the federated behaviour.

Use the provider e[ndpoints documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132048/openid-endpoints)

like so:

```
providers = {
    'Google'   : 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',
    'Yahoo'    : 'yahoo.com',
    'MySpace'  : 'myspace.com',
    'AOL'      : 'aol.com',
    'MyOpenID' : 'myopenid.com'
    # add more here
}
```

**Edit on small mistake** 
Just make links like `users.create_login_url(dest_url="/register/",federated_identity=uri)` where uri is the uri of the above obj, and `register` your login handler.

As soon as you push the app on production this ugly simple login page that you use on the dev server will be replace by one of the above providers login screen.

I had the same question when I started developing with app engine

Comment: I'm still thinking I'm a bit of a thickie today, sorry. I'm using `UserService::createLoginUrl('yahoo.com', "Some Name"));` and it ends up back on `http://localhost:10080/_ah/login?email=test%40example.com&continue=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A10080%2Fyahoo.com&action=Login` which I don't have a handler, but that's not important, look at the continue bit. The documetation says that the first parameter is the redirect URL. IS this another GAE and PHPism?

Comment: And when I write a handler for _ah/login that just redirects to the continue URL, nothing happens.

Comment: Just make an app on Appengine, push it and test. It should be fine. Same aspects on PHP and Python for the users service.

Comment: On python for example on google federated login (the first url), on the deb server that is `http://localhost:8080/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/register/`

Comment: @NigelJohnson see edited answer. I forgot the usage of create url and as i see it's not well documented on the examples that I copy pasted.

Comment: Yep, I just found that in the PHP source code as well so I added it and it seems to work once I fix the rel='external' issue in my links and JQuery played nice. Now for the next question(s) Yahoo give me a url not an email address!!! Noooo!!!! :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @NigelJohnson good luck. Do some research on the endpoints. Maybe they changed. I had similar issue with the nickname property. I have a bounty of 50 points. You'll find it at my asked questions. Maybe that will help a bit.